# Debugging javascript web page running on windows application

Tags: debugging, microsoft-edge

Do we have any way to debug javascript pages integrated into a windows application?
Currently, we have F12 IEChooser by Microsoft, but that is outdated. It's not so comfortable for debugging. Breakpoints don't work often.
I know we have EdgeHTML, I've tried installing this, But I didn't find a way to debug javascript code running in windows application.  We have something called script attacher, that's how we used F12 to debug the same. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please inform us whether you are using web browser control or you are using web view control in your Windows app? Here are some helpful links https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Mar/08/Debugging-the-Web-Browser-Control-with-FireBug and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-a-webview-control?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

There's a neatly written blog post on this. Looks like this is what you asked for.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jul/06/javascript-debugging-in-a-web-browser-control-with-visual-studio